# maven custom plugin configuration

Tags: maven

I have a maven multimodule project and I was hoping i could use profiles to customize the configuration of a plugin for two cases based on a POM property but it turns out profiles can only be activated by external properties and not by POM properties so now I am looking for another way to have a different project configuration and i wanted to get some ideas. Here is my setup

I have a 3-levels tree: A root parent POM X with many many submodules A, B, C, ... and each of these modules has 2 submodules 1 and 2 (so A1, A2, B1, B2, etc.)

what i need to do is customize the configuration of a leaf module for all modules of type 1 and another for all modules of type 2. I am trying to avoid making all 1's share a common parent and all 2's another (different) common parent since 1 and 2 already share some data from their respective parent (A or B of example). If there is no other way, I will push down all the common data from A to A1 and A2 (not ideal, DRY principle)and make all 1's inherit from a common 1 parent, but i'm trying to avoid this. Like i said, something i tried was to set a property in the leaves of the tree with a property specifying if it was a 1 or a 2 and then putting the two different profiles in the grandparent POM X and activating the profile based on the property. This didn't work.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please consider revising this question with a diagram illustrating your module layout and specifying the plugins you are using - with pom.xml snippets as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can accomplish your goal with `<pluginManagement>`

For example, in your parent POM, you have something like this:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
         <systemPropertyVariables>
              <vendor.license.file>../licenses/vendor.lic</vendor.license.file>
         </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

Which defines Surefire version 2.5 in for the POM's child modules. Note that you can actually put more than just the version in the plugin configuration, such as a configuration that child projects inherit (and override). See [Maven POM Reference - Plugin Management](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

Comment: Your solution doesn't allow to have two different configurations, which is what i need:

  if (is of type 1) { use config 1} else if (is of type 2) { use config 2}

Comment: Do "type 1" and "type 2" have different parent POMs?  Also, can you activate your profile perhaps based on something other than a property, i.e. presence of a file? Can you perhaps make a profile in each sub-module and make it "active by default?"

Comment: Right now they have a common parent, like i said in my OP, there is A1, A2, so they share a parent A, and B1, B2 share a parent B. The option i mentioned is making A1 and B1 share a parent common1 instead and A2 B2 share a parent common2. But i **do** have common information in A and in B which would need to be pushed down and duplicated in A1 and A2